# Discover which submit button pressed in validation method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation

I'm writing a new custom validator for MVC4. Done this several times. This time though I need to know which submit button was pressed, there are multiple submits on the form which do slightly different things based on their value.

Given the common way of writing a new adapter:

```
 $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add(
            'requiredforsubmitvalue', ['submitValue'], function (options) {
                options.rules['requiredforsubmitvalue'] = options.params;
                options.messages['requiredforsubmitvalue'] = options.message;
            });
    $.validator.addMethod("requiredforsubmitvalue", function (value, element, params) {

        //which submit button pressed?
    });
```

How do I identify which submit button has been pressed? Is this even possible?

Comment: `var btn = $("input[type=submit]:focus");` ? Added as answer (just in case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you the focused (pressed) submit button:

```
var btn = $("input[type=submit]:focus");
```